# Catch all un-caught exceptions in python

Tags: python, exception, python-3.4

I am trying to make it so all uncaught exception are logged to file without having to put a try/catch block around each of my scripts.

At the moment, I have made a module that I import into all scripts.
I would like to be able in this module to run some python that would catch uncaught exceptions.

I have read about the module atexit, but it's not quite what I need, I think.
However there might be something I'm not aware of in this module?

I need to do that because I run my scripts via the Task Scheduler, and this gives you only error code, not anything helpful like a stacktrace

Comment: Forgot to comment to say that the duplicate was exactly what I was looking for, thanks to the person who marked it.